# Can't connect to download plugins issuing command create-controller

Tags: grails

I'm new to grails ,I just download grails 2.1.0 and install a sample project named helloWorld, when I try to create a controller hello issuing command  `create-controller hello`, below errors show up, seeming to be a connection problem. My computer need to access the internet via proxy server of my company.

> grails> create-controller hello
>   | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies
>   |Error Failed to install plugin [cache-1.0.0]. Plugin has missing JAR dependencies.
>   | Resolving plugin JAR dependencies.
>   | Error Error running script create-controller hello:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Actually I configure a proxy as below commands ,but doesn't work either. I'm wondering if there is a manual way to download and install plugins.

> grails add-proxy client --host=50.2.221.9 --port=80
>   grails set-proxy client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins can be downloaded easily, but the real problem are dependencies. Grails 2.x is configured to use ivy and optionally maven, you need to configure that tools. You can read about that in

[Proxy settings with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921364/proxy-settings-with-ivy)

Comment: export ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080" works, thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to install from file. Just see official documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/install-plugin.html

Example: `grails install-plugin ../grails-bar-1.0.zip`

Plugins can be downloaded from http://grails.org/plugins/
You may also need to comment lines with external repositories in BuildConfig.groovy

I cannot help you with proxy configuration though.

Comment: hi,I download cache 1.0 plugin, but not work. 
error info:
E:\MyDoc\Programming\java\projects\eclipse\4.2\helloWorld>grails install-plugin e:\download\soft\cache-1.0.0.zip 1.0.0
| Error resolving plugin [name:\download\soft\cache-1.0.0.zip, group:e, version:1.0.0]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [e:\download\soft\cache-1.0.0.zip] and version [1.0.0]