# Jenkins with Ivy under a proxy firewall

Tags: ant, jenkins, firewall, ivy

I´m trying to integrate Ivy with jenkins.
When I run the target below:

```
<!-- Retrieve dependencies with Ivy -->
<target name="resolve" depends="init">
    <ivy:retrieve conf="default" type="jar,bundle"
        pattern="${result}/lib/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
</target>
```

> [ivy:retrieve]    ==== public: tried
>   [ivy:retrieve]    http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/vaadin-server/7.2.6/vaadin-server-7.2.6.pom

The problem is that I already configured the proxy settings for jenkins under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Manage plugins" -> "HTTP Proxy Configuration",   but somehow this configuration is not used by ivy:resolve command

Any Ideas?

My setup is:

- A Vaadin web site
- Ivy plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Ivy+Plugin)
- Jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Manage Jenkins" -> "Manage plugins" -> "HTTP Proxy Configuration"

That proxy setting it to retrieve the plugins. It is a not a proxy setting for your node/system.

Read this answer on how to set proxy in Ant itself
**[Proxy settings with ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921364/proxy-settings-with-ivy)**

Comment: Is there a way to hide your password?

Comment: Use [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin. Under Global Configuration, setup Global Password (even Jenkins admins will see `****`). Under Job Configuration, enable Global Passwords. In build step (script/ANT/anything) use the configured Global Password as you would any other environment variable. Even console log will display `****`.

Comment: I tried https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin and I was easier for me.