# Liferay 6.2 ga6 creating first portlet issue

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

i am using liferay 6.2 ga6 after installation when i am trying to create a new portlet it shows below error

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\liferay-basic-ga6\plugins\portlets\build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\liferay-basic-ga6\plugins\build-common-plugins.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\liferay-basic-ga6\plugins\build-common.xml:60: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\liferay-basic-ga6\plugins\build-common-ivy.xml:130: The following error occurred while executing this line:
E:\liferay-basic-ga6\plugins\build-common-ivy.xml:81: HTTP Authorization failure
```

then i referred below blog

https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74382032

and made below changes

> ivy.jar.url=https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-public-snapshots/com/liferay/org.apache.ivy/${ivy.version}/org.apache.ivy-${ivy.version}.jar

i m getting the below error:

```
Buildfile: M:\xxx\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\portlets\build.xml
[ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.4.0 - 20130110142753 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = M:\xxx\plugins\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2\ivy-settings.xml
```

and finally error which is shown in image  please check here

[image]

please help me resolve this issue .it would be great help.

Comment: Without making the new blog changes,could you try checking if the ivy url is accessible to you via browser and command prompt.Looks like a proxy issue.

Comment: ivy url is not accessible first it shows access denied and provides login link and when clicked on that 404 error

Comment: Could you plz post screenshots for the same,also you will need to have proxy URL from internet options->LAN settings.Asn also your username/password for accessing the proxy

Comment: What command are you running? And on which location?

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to access this URL,you seem to be behind a proxy server.
Try this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921364/proxy-settings-with-ivy) and [ivy proxy settings](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/setproxy.html) to set your proxy settings.
In essence you need to proxy details to allow ivy to connect to repository for fetching artifacts,in your ivy settings xml file

```
<setproxy proxyhost="${proxy.host}"
      proxyport="${proxy.port}"
      nonproxyhosts="xyz.svn.com"/>
```

Comment: in build-common-ivy.xml file                                                            <setproxy proxyhost="172.21.2.17" proxyport="80"/>   is added but not working .let me know if any changes need to be made as shown in the link which provided.

Comment: As per the error logs,it seems your proxy server is incorrectly configured.Could you please try accessing the ivy and cdn urls via browser first,in case it is not accessible,then get it sorted from network team,which has configured this proxy.